# parse httpd log in bash

Tags: linux, bash, apache

my httpd log has the following format

```
123.251.0.000 - - [05/Sep/2014:18:19:24 -0700] "GET /myapp/MyService?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3 HTTP/1.1" 200 15138 "-" "-"
```

I need to extract the following fields and display on a line:

```
IP value1 httpResponseCode(eg.200), dataLength
```

what's the most efficient way to do this in bash?

Comment: Are all of your log entries exactly the same format ? If not will you be pre filtering so that only the entries of this format get passed on to the code you need ?

Comment: @lain: yes assume all log entries are of the same format, try to be fault-tolerent though

Comment: @lain: please refrain from using offensive or unprofessional words on stackoverflow.  No graffiti allowed here.

Comment: Please then refrain from asking give me teh codez questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Linux, chances are that you also have GNU `awk` installed.  If so:

```
$ awk 'match ($7, /param1=([^& ]*)/, m) { print $1, m[1], $9",", $10 }' http.log
```

gives:

```
123.251.0.000 value1 200, 15138
```

This works as long as `value1` hasn't got an ampersand or space in it, which they shouldn't if the request has been escaped correctly.

Comment: if param1 and param2 or param3 can shift positions, this won't work.  param1 might not always be the first, how do I make it to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tmp.txt 
123.251.0.000 - - [05/Sep/2014:18:19:24 -0700] "GET /myapp/MyService?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3 HTTP/1.1" 200 15138 "-" "-"

$ awk '{ print "IP", $1, $9, $10 }' tmp.txt
IP 123.251.0.000 200 15138
```

Comment: Corrected, is this what you are after?

Comment: It seems the OP is... The example answer shows `value1` as the second column.

Comment: Do you need a literal string "value1" as the second column?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding several things. IP is not meant to be the string literal 'IP' it is meant to be the IP Address parsed from the log entry. Similarly value1 is meant to be the value of param1 parsed from the log entry.

Comment: Ahh right, I didn't scroll the URL so I missed the "value1" bit.